# Which camera to buy?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-recommendation

My sister needs a camera.
Can anyone guide me which one to buy, as I have no knowledge about it.

She is studying Architecture, and she often goes for site seeing and she needs to take picture(mainly buildings, structure, interior)

I asked some of my friends which camera will be good for her, they said  Point & Shoot will be good.
There are many point and shoot cameras available in the market which one to buy? can some one give me some more specification or details, so that I can buy a good camera to my sis, from architectural view point.

Preferred brand- Nikon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A camera purchase has a huge number of personal decisions that have to be made. Its nearly impossible to do it for someone else. You write "per her requirements" but you don't mention any of them.

You can spend between $200 and $1200 or so on a "point and shoot". What is your budget? Here is a link to a review by one of the regulars here of a $1200 Nikon point-n-shoot. http://www.neocamera.com/camera/nikon/a/review
Read it and see at least what the reviewer thought were important features and specs.

Comment: my budget is in INR 20,000 which will be $350 in usa

Comment: This one is well reviewed, is about $300 at Amazon. My wife has an older model and loves it. Canon PowerShot S100.

Comment: You can spend a lot more than $1200 if you consider the Sony RX1 a point and shoot :-)